How to set siunitx S column properties globally?
How to set up S columns in tabularray globally so that:

all numbers in S columns are displayed in the format 3.11112222333344445e-6 with 17 decimal figures and exponent as e-##
larger numbers are rounded to 17 figures only in tables
exponent is not detached from the number
columns do not overlap
there is no unnecessary gap between the columns

I've tried
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{
    scientific-notation=true,
    output-exponent-marker=$\rmfamily{e}$,
    table-format=2.17e2,
    table-figures-integer = 2,  % Number of integer digits
    table-figures-decimal = 17  % Number of decimal digits
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={cSSS}}
        \toprule
         & & & \\
        \midrule
        1 &
        1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 &
        1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 &
        1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 &
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}

and the issued are:

bad spacing
e is detached from the previous number
numbers with many decimals are not rounded


Apply the required settings only in tblr.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\sisetup{
  scientific-notation=true,
  output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}},
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tblr}{\sisetup{
  table-format=2.17e-2,
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=17,
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={cSSS},rowhead=1}
  \toprule
  A & {{{B}}} & {{{C}}} & {{{D}}} \\
  \midrule
  1 &
  1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 &
  1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 &
  1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\num{1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12}

\end{document}



Your MWE has several problems:

For table you define four columns, however in table body you use five.
last row is not properly terminated -- missed is \\  at the end of row.
For numbers in table you define that have 17 decimal digits, however they actually have 51 decimal digits. Consequently this number cannot be properly shown in defined S columns.
If you like to show only 17 decimal digits, you should round those numbers accordingly. For example as I do in my MWE.
Even rounded numbers to 17 digits make table to wide, that can be fit in text block area. To remedy this, you have two chooses:

round numbers to smaller number of decimal digits
show table in landscape oriented page (as I do in the MWE below)


It is not clear what is contents in the first row (in MWE I suppose, that there are not decimal numbers)
It also is not clear why you for numbers select two integer digits, when in table they have just one.

An example of MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}
\sisetup{
    table-format = 1.17e-2,
    round-precision = 17,
    round-mode = places,
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {c *{3}{S}},
             row{1}  = {guard}
             }
    \toprule
    &   &   &   \\
    \midrule
1   & 1.123 131 313 123 081 623 876 192 369 163 981 629 371 692 376 192 376e-12 
        & 1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 
            & 1.123131313123081623876192369163981629371692376192376e-12 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}


